# .HTACCESS Redirect No Subdomain To WWW and Keep The Rest

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've done alot of searching for this, yet I have not been able to find an answer.

I'm looking to :

1) Redirect Only blank Subdomains to WWW.  In Example :

```
http://website.com --> http://www.website.com
```

BUT!

2) I need to not redirect `http://*.website.com` as I'm using wildcard subdomains for a multitude of subdomains.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(website\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.